# What does OutputResponse[sys, { {u1,u2,u3}, {v1,v2,v3} } ] do?

Tags: signal-processing

I am puzzled by the result of `OutputResponse[sys, {{u1,u2,u3},{v1,v2,v3}}]`.  OutputResponse  is used this way in the first  "Application"  in the documentation for [`KalmanEstimator`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KalmanEstimator.html?q=KalmanEstimator/%22KalmanEstimatoe%22).  I don't see much in the documentation for [`OutputResponse`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OutputResponse.html?q=OutputResponse) that helps me understand what it is doing here.  Consider the following:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a={{a11,a12},{a21,a22}};
b={{b11,b12},{b21,b22}};
c= {{c1,c2}};
d= {{d1,d2}};
ssm=StateSpaceModel[{a, b, c, d}, SamplingPeriod->t];
y=OutputResponse[ssm, {{u1,u2,u3},{v1,v2,v3}}];
```

I was able to seperate (`y`) above into the portion from  `{u1,u2,u3}`  and the portion from  `{v1,v2,v3}` as follows.

```
yu=OutputResponse[ssm, {{u1,u2,u3},{0,0,0}}];
yv=OutputResponse[ssm, {{0,0,0},{v1,v2,v3}}];
Simplify[y==yu+yv]

(* True *)
```

I was also able to see that `OutputResponse[ssm1, {{u1,u2,u3},{0,0,0}}] ===
OutputResponse[ssm2, {{0,0,0},{u1,u2,u3}}]`
when `ssm1` and `ssm2` are related by rearanging matrices `(a, b, c, d)` as follows.

```
ssm1=ssm;
ar=Reverse/@Reverse@a;
br=Reverse/@Reverse@b;
cr=Reverse/@Reverse@c;
dr=Reverse/@Reverse@d;
ssm2=StateSpaceModel[{ar,br,cr,dr}, SamplingPeriod->t];
OutputResponse[ssm1, {{u1,u2,u3},{0,0,0}}]===
   OutputResponse[ssm2, {{0,0,0},{u1,u2,u3}}]

(* True *)
```

The result we get from  `OutputResponse[ ssm, { {u1,u2,u3}, {v1,v2,v3} }]`,
is the response of (`ssm`) to what input?  When (`ssm`) is a `StateSpaceModel`.